# Convert ASCII code to hexadecimal in a Unix shell script

Tags: unix, shell, ascii, hex

I'd like to convert **ASCII code** (like `-`, `_`, `.`, etc.) in **hexadecimal** representation in Unix shell (without bc command). For example, `-` => `%2d`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can `sed`/`awk`/`perl` etc be used?

Comment: only sed or bash/sh shell please ;)

Answer (score 9):

This works in Bash, Dash (sh), ksh, zsh and ash and uses only builtins:

**Edit:**

Here is a version of ord that outputs in hex and chr that accepts hex input:

```
ordhex ()
{
    printf '%x' "'$1"
}

chrhex ()
{
    printf \\x"$1"
}
```

The original decimal versions:

```
ord ()
{
    echo -n $(( ( 256 + $(printf '%d' "'$1"))%256 ))
}
```

Examples (with added newlines):

```
$ ord ' '
32
$ ord _
95
$ ord A
65
$ ord '*'
42
$ ord \~
126
```

Here is the corresponding `chr`:

```
chr ()
{
    printf \\$(($1/64*100+$1%64/8*10+$1%8))
}
```

Examples:

```
$ chr 125
}
$ chr 42
*
$ chr 0 | xxd
0000000: 00                                       .
$ chr 255 | xxd
0000000: ff                                       .
```

Comment: thx but ord function gives me decimal value, I'd like the hexadecimal value of the ascii code, thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e 'print ord("_"), "\n"'
```

Comment: thx a lot, I'll use this expression with unpack : perl -e 'print unpack("H*","-"), "\n"'

Answer (score 0):

> python -c 'import sys; print "{0:02x}".format(ord(sys.argv[1]))' '_'

or

> python -c 'print "{0:02x}".format(ord("_"))'

I agree that it's not the nicest one-liner, but I couldn't resist after seeing the Perl based answer .

Answer (score 0):

The following works in the ksh version I'm using:

```
chr ()
{
    printf \\x$1
}
```